# How to obtain only repeated lines for a specific column in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

Imagine I have this file in bash:

```
1 3 6 name1
1 2 7 name2
3 4 2 name1
2 2 2 name3
7 8 2 name2
1 2 9 name4
```

How could I extract just those lines which present the field "name" repeated and sort them?

My expected output would be:

```
1 3 6 name1
3 4 2 name1
1 2 7 name2
7 8 2 name2
```

I was trying to use `sort -k4,4 myfile | uniq -D`, but I don't find how to tell `uniq` to work with the 4th column.
Thanks!

Comment: Do the repetitions always occur only twice?

Comment: No, the repetitions can occur different times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. You need to skip fields preceding the last one.

```
$ sort -k4 file | uniq -f3 -D
1 3 6 name1
3 4 2 name1
1 2 7 name2
7 8 2 name2
```

Comment: Nice. My attempt was a little more confusing. With GNU grep: `sort -k 4,4 file | grep -Poz '([0-9]+ ){3}([^ ]+)\n(([0-9]+ ){3}\2\n)+'`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  a[$NF]++
  b[$NF]=(b[$NF]?b[$NF] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(a[i]>1){
      print b[i]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

OR in case you want to sort the output try following then.

```
awk '
{
  a[$NF]++
  b[$NF]=(b[$NF]?b[$NF] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(a[i]>1){
      print b[i]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file  |  sort -k4
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk + sort`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{freq[$NF]++; next} freq[$NF] > 1' file{,} | sort -k4
```

```
1 3 6 name1
3 4 2 name1
1 2 7 name2
7 8 2 name2
```